# Android Build Variants equivalent in Windows Phone (8.1)

Tags: android, gradle, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm kind of new to Windows Phone (8.1+) development and was wondering if there was something similar to Build Variants on Android ?

So basically I have an application which must be generated for several clients with minor changes (a few texts and images) so if there is a way to avoid creating a new project for each one of them I would be great.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better start with [Build Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx)

Using several configurations you can define different constants to Use with `#if #elif #endif` and setting different pre/post bail events

Here is [tutorial to start](http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/custom-build-configurations-visualstudio/)

**UPD**
For different manifest for each configuration you have to manually edit .csproj file. Find there `<AppxManifest>` tag and replace it with several tags with condition. For Ex:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppxManifest Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'FirstAppConfigurationName' And '$(Configuration)' != 'SecondAppConfigurationName'" Include="DefaultPackage.appxmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AppxManifest>
    <AppxManifest Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'FirstAppConfigurationName'" Include="FirstAppPackage.appxmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AppxManifest>
    <AppxManifest Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'SecondAppConfigurationName'" Include="SecondAppPackage.appxmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AppxManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks this will do it for the most part. Is there a way to change the app name (from package.appxmanifest) ?

Comment: @kimimsc Yes, but you have to manually edit csproj to Conditionally include different manifests. I'll update answer later

Comment: @adD1ma Thanks. The only problem is that now I get an error saying that my project has more than one manifest file. Did I miss something ?

Comment: @adD1ma Any idea why ? [cf. last comment]

Comment: @kimimsc may be error in conditions. check if two of them is true